# Variable doesn't get set properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When a user clicks on the delete button on the index page. The modal pops up and with the first function the URL path gets passed to the `taskdestroylink` attribute of the delete button in the modal. Until now everything works fine. Everytime I click on the link the attribute gets set properly.

The second function is sending the AJAX request to the server. On page reload the first request works fine, but the second one keeps the route of the first one. So `var href` gets set properly for the first time, but if I try to delete another task the `href` value still belong to the first one. It's weird since as I mentioned the `taskdestroylink` attribute shows the new value in the DOM.

So what's the problem with `var href = $(this).data("taskdestroylink");`? Why doesn't it set the new value?

Modal get's opened by clicking this link:

```
<li>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" role="button" data-target="#delete-task-modal" class="open-delete-task-modal" data-taskdeletelink="<%= user_task_path(current_user, task) %>">Delete Task</a>
</li>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="deletetaskclose">Close</button>
  <a href="#" id="delete-task-link" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-taskdestroylink >Delete Task</a> 
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.open-delete-task-modal', function (event) {
  var taskDeleteLink = $(this).data("taskdeletelink");
  $('#delete-task-link').attr("data-taskdestroylink", taskDeleteLink);
});

$(document).on('click', '#delete-task-link', function (event) {
  var href = $(this).data("taskdestroylink");
  alert(href);
  $.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: href,
    dataType: "script"
  });
});
```

Comment: why are you mixing data() and attr()?

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: You are using data() to read and attr() to write

Comment: How can you write without attribute? This is my first time writing with jquery. I always do with html.

Comment: But I guess that shouldn't cause the problem since it's working fine on page load.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: haha, it solved the problem. Still don't get it though.

Comment: You could write it in answer. If you also know the reason why it didn't work, you could include that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad idea to mix `data()` and `attr()` so pick one and stick with it.

Change

```
.attr("data-taskdestroylink", taskDeleteLink);
```

to

```
.data("taskdestroylink", taskDeleteLink);
```

`data()` uses its own internal storage and not the actual attributes.